# Generic method declaration from examlab

Tags: java, generics

```
abstract class TypeTest<K extends Number> {
    public abstract <K> K useMe(Object k); //OK
    public abstract <K> TypeTest<? extends Number> useMe(TypeTest<? super K> k);  //OK
    public abstract <K> TypeTest<? super Number> useMe(TypeTest<? extends K> k);  //error
    public abstract <V extends K> TypeTest<V> useMe(TypeTest<V> k);  //OK
}
```

answer from ExamLab is the declaration above are OK,but I found the 3rd compiled error.And I want to know why,thanks!

I found it is fine in Eclipse but compile error in Editplus with jdk1.7,I want to confirm whether the 3rd line declaration is right.

compile error info

```
TypeTest.java:4: 错误: 类型参数? extends K#1不在类型变量K#2的范围内
    public abstract <K> TypeTest<? super Number> useMe(TypeTest<? extends K>
 k);  //error
                                                                ^
  其中, K#1,K#2是类型变量:
    K#1扩展已在方法 <K#1>useMe(TypeTest<? extends K#1>)中声明的Object
    K#2扩展已在类 TypeTest中声明的Number
1 个错误
请按任意键继续. . .
```

I tried times to change its compile info from Chinese into English but fail only messy code"??".   Thanks!

Comment: add the error message

Comment: Read the error message: it explains why.

Comment: I am sorry that I am not quite understand the error message clearly and want to confirm whether the problem is on **useMe(TypeTest<? extends K> k)** for its boundary is larger than class declaration.

Comment: Then post it instead of letting us guess it. This line compiles fine here. Lines 2 and 3 are in conflict, though.

Comment: I updated the question and post the compile error info but cannot change them into English but only messy code ??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer is for reference from another forums:

Note that the method type parameter  is not the same as the class type parameter . The method type parameter  shadows the class type parameter .

In the method

```
view plainprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped
public abstract <K> TypeTest<? super Number> useMe(TypeTest<? extends K> k);
```

the type parameter  is resolved to java.lang.Object as it is the upper bound that is to be resolved.

But TypeTest would also include those cases ( for example TypeTest ) that are not within the higher bound set by the class parameter cause as per the class parameter  TypeTest's type parameter can be anything that extends Number.

Hence the compilation fails.

Note that this compiles successfully with JDK versions 1.6.0_43 or lower but fails with JDK versions 1.6.0_45 or higher.

I guess what the question was trying to test is if you understand that the method type parameter shadows the class type parameter.